# like two peas in a pod.

Tags: expressions

In Dutch we have the expression (translated) "they are two hands on one belly" meaning that they always stick together. It seems that "like two peas in a pod" doesn't cover that. Is there an equivalent expression in English?

Comment: "Stick like glue"?
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick%20like%20glue

Answer (score 10):

**joined at the hip**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/joined+at+the+hip)

> spending a lot of time with someone else, often a close friend

As in:

> Every time I see Jenna, Kelli is right there with her. Those two are
>   really joined at the hip these days.

Comment: I'd agree with that. After all we're not talking about people who are genuinely conjoined any more than the Dutch expression refers to people who are really both touching the same stomach.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need an idiom (unless you want one); there is a simple English word that means the same thing.

[**Inseparable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inseparable):

> **2** : seemingly always together : very intimate · *inseparable* friends